# Symbolic link difference between cp -sr and ln -s

Tags: linux, bash, unix, symlink

I'm trying to make symbolic links in my Dropbox so that I don't have duplicate files all over my computer (file space is limited). I've come across some confusing behavior in ln -s vs. cp -s. Basically, ln -s seems to make a link to the original folder, but then copies all the files within the folder to a new location. cp -sr recursively makes links to all files within the folder (which is the desired behavior).

For example:

```
nate@auerilas ~ $ mkdir ~/Desktop/test_ln
nate@auerilas ~ $ mkdir ~/Desktop/test_cp
nate@auerilas ~ $ cp -sr ~/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/ ~/Desktop/test_cp
nate@auerilas ~ $ ln -s ~/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/ ~/Desktop/test_ln

nate@auerilas ~ $ cd ~/Desktop/test_cp/Prec
nate@auerilas ~/Desktop/test_cp/Prec $ ls -ls
total 52
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 65 Apr 27 11:40 readme.txt -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/readme.txt
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_01.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_01.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_02.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_02.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_03.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_03.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_04.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_04.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_05.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_05.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_06.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_06.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_07.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_07.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_08.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_08.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_09.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_09.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_10.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_10.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_11.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_11.tif
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 nate nate 76 Apr 27 11:40 wc2.0_30s_prec_12.tif -> /home/nate/Documents/GIS_Files/WorldClim2/Monthly/Prec/wc2.0_30s_prec_12.tif

nate@auerilas ~ $ cd ~/Desktop/test_ln/Prec
nate@auerilas ~/Desktop/test_ln/Prec $ ls -ls
total 1030608
    8 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate      256 Jul  4  2016 readme.txt
74828 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 76618603 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_01.tif
76620 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 78453928 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_02.tif
86664 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 88738160 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_03.tif
89424 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 91564709 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_04.tif
88272 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 90386408 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_05.tif
90364 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 92524861 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_06.tif
92252 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 94459125 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_07.tif
94700 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 96964870 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_08.tif
88708 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 90829431 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_09.tif
92756 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 94977702 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_10.tif
79808 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 81716504 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_11.tif
76204 -rw-rw-r-- 1 nate nate 78025342 Jun 30  2016 wc2.0_30s_prec_12.tif
```

Note the difference in file sizes between the two methods, and the lack of a link for the files made by ln -s. If I go into my file browser and right click to look at the properties, I also see something different.

ln -s

```
Type Image
Size 76.6 MB
Location /home/nate/Desktop/test_ln/Prec
```

cp -sr

```
Type Link to Image
Link target /home/nate/Documents/GIS_File..nthly/Prec/wc2.0...
Size 76.6 MB
Location /home/nate/Desktop/test_cp/Prec
```

So cp -sr seems to be actually linking each file in a directory, whereas ln -s seems to link the top folder only and copying the files within the folder, thus duplicating files.

Is that correct?

The problem is that if I use cp -sr, only the files themselves are linked, not the top folder. So if I add or delete a file on my harddrive, the change isn't then copied to Dropbox

Running Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: In the future, this is probably a better fit for [unix.se] than StackOverflow, being a generic "how do UNIX tools work?" question as opposed to something more squarely focused on scripting.

Comment: `ln` does not copy your files or duplicate them: you just "jum" in your dropbox with cd. Try `readlink .` in test_ln directory.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. Here's `info cp` explicitly saying that it only links non-directories:

> ```
> ‘-s’
> ‘--symbolic-link’
>      Make symbolic links instead of copies of non-directories.
> ```

Comment: so how to I have ln -s avoid making a copy of files within the directory. for example, with ln -s, now I have two 75 MB files, right?

Comment: @Nate No, `ln` doesn't make copies. A link to a directory is not the same as a copy of a directory, even though you can see the contents in two places

Comment: So even though the contents of the ln linked folder have a filepath that points to the file itself, like /Desktop/test_ln/.../ and a large file size, its still just pointing to the original file in the /Documents/GIS_Files/ folder?

Comment: Right. Edit/rename/delete one and see.

Comment: Gotcha. Just a tad confused because the filesize and filepath of a file within a sym-linked folder are different (and look as though the file has been copied) as opposed to sym-linking the file itself. Thanks!

Comment: The filesizes are different?